# call a method of nested interface from enclosing class

Tags: java, callback

Let's suppose I have a class **OuterClass** which has a method **classMethod()** and an nested interface **NastedInterface** which in its turn has a method **callback()**. So how can I call the method of the interface **callback()** in the method of class **classMethod()**?

My goal is to be able to implement **OuterClass.NastedInterface** in other classes and do some operations in the **callback()** method, which will be called when the **classMethod()** will be called in **OuterClass**. 
The code will look like something like this.

```
public class OuterClass {
    public void classMethod(){
        if(SOME_CONDITION){
            \\ here I want to call the **callback()** method of **NastedInterface**
        } 
    }

    public interface NastedInterface {
        void callback();
    }
}
```

And the class that will implement this interface should look like something like this.

```
public class TestClass implements OuterClass.NastedInterface {
    @Override
    public void callback (){
        DO SOMETHING....
    }
}
```

Basically I want to create a callback mechanism, such as I have used many times in Android. For example the View.OnClickListener or all other such kind of ON_SOMETHINK_LISTENER s.

May be I am going in wrong direction, and I need to create such a mechanism in other way?

Comment: I removed your android tag because this is java question.

Comment: You need a reference to an instance of implementing class to invoke the method.

Comment: Ops. Sorry) I actually need this for android but, yes, you are right - this is fully JAVA question.

Comment: no worries :) Is this a homework question? If so, be sure to tag that so people can help without giving you the answer.

Comment: Everyone's getting to the right answer, but just incase you miss it, you'll need a `NastedInterface interfaceToCall = new TestClass()`

Just remember you won't be able to call any methods in `TestClass` using `interfaceToCall` if they aren't in `NastedInterface`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me to to understand other's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a member variable in your `OuterClass` that holds an instance of `NestedInterface`.  Add a setter method that sets that variable, and make it public.

Make sure the check that the member isn't null before calling `callback`.

Answer (score 1):

Outerclass needs to have a reference to the TestClass for this work.

So:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private NastedInterface interfaceToCall;

    public void classMethod(){
        if(SOME_CONDITION){
            \\ here I want to call the **callback()** method of **NastedInterface**
            if(interfaceToCall != null)
            {
               interfaceToCall.callback();
            }
        } 
    }

    public interface NastedInterface {
        void callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for answers, I solved the problem and every answer here helped me in some way. But as the solution was not exactly how how suggested in answers, I will write it here for people who may need it in the future.

```
public class OuterClass {
    private NastedInterface nastedInterface;

    //In the constructor I am assigning the reference of the parent class 
    // of some other classes in my app which all may need to be notified when 
    // **callback()** has happened
    public OuterClass(){
        nastedInterface = TestClassParent.getInstance;
    }

    public void classMethod(){
        if(nastedInterface != null){
            nastedInterface.callback();
        } 
    }

    public interface NastedInterface {
        void callback();
    }
}
```

So here I have a class which will be the parent of some other classes and will implement NastedInterface.

```
public class TestClassParent implements OuterClass.NastedInterface {
    private static TestClassParent instance;

    public static TestClassParent getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
              instance = new TestClassParent();
         }

        return instance;
    } 

 @Override
 public void callback(){
     //I will override it in subclasses and do what I need in each class
 }
}
```

And after this I can receive **callback()** event in any class that extends **TestClassParent**. For example:

```
public class TestClass1 extends TestClassParent {

    @Override
    public void callback (){
        DO SOMETHING....
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TestClass2 extends TestClassParent {

    @Override
    public void callback (){
        DO SOMETHING ELSE....
    }
}
```